# A term for: When a taste or smell of a product is being concealed by another product

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, phrase-requests

Let's say, we create a smoothie and some ingredients are much stronger than others and they literally beat out the taste/smell of the other ingredients.

> a. We can't add durian because it will _______ the other flavours
>   b. Nobody can smell the apricot because it is _______ by the other fruits

Is there a specific word or slang expression for it?

Comment: *Mask*, *dominate*, *overpower*, *overwhelm*, *override*? If you're looking for a specific word, you need to be more exact.

Comment: @JasonBassford thank you, yes, correct that words are very close, and actually what I was looking for, but perhaps there is a slang that refers to smell of products only

Comment: You'll probably find that Jason's word "mask" is very fitting for this usage. The first dictionary example sentence I found for it was "spices that mask the strong flavor of the meat". An internet search for such a thing will probably show you that mask is very common for what you mean. For example masking a scent. But maybe there is a more specific word, not sure.

Comment: No one, including the OP has consulted a dictionary as yet, though. Let alone use cases.

Comment: +1 Good question. However, no prior homework is shown. Voting to close on that account alone.

Comment: What about adjective: We can't add durian because it is **strong-smelling** than
other flavours.

Comment: @Kris Actually, looked in the dictionary without luck, because you need to know exactly what your are looking without long description

Comment: @Eddy Nearly but it should be comparative “…because it is **stronger smelling** than the other flavours…”

Comment: I'll note that it's possible for one odor to "mask" another, even though, when smelled separately, it is not "stronger smelling".  Rather, it twists the combined odor in some fashion, possibly by hinting of another familiar (and less offensive) odor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dominate

Usage:

> Use in high concentrations causes the syrup flavour to **dominate** other flavours. Syrup tends to **mask** delicate flavours such as vanilla.

Reference,  example found in Google Books: ['The Complete Technology Book on Flavoured Ice Cream' ASIA PACIFIC BUSINESS PRESS Inc., Jan 1, 2006](https://books.google.pl/books?id=kCKtAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=dominate%20other%20flavours&source=bl&ots=YaDP3bUgGX&sig=PIsedlTieUmchdyPPn3LBTm_BLQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjomaaE1aveAhUIfywKHUldARcQ6AEwEnoECAAQAQ)

Credit goes to Jason Bassford in the comments

Comment: Ups, my bad! I didn't read previous comments very carefully

Comment: Fixed the edit, otherwise I can't delete my comment underneath, and frankly it's not important to say "edit", everything is recorded in the time stamp. By all means,  please edit and say the title of the book where you found the excerpt, so my username disappears. You could place ***mask*** in bold, to add emphasis

Answer (score 0):

to **disguise**    [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/disguise)

> b. To make indistinct or difficult to perceive

As in:

> ... disguised the bad taste of the medicine with lemon syrup.

and your example

> We can't add durian because it will disguise the other flavours.